# return value as text into textarea

Tags: php, wordpress, return-value, advanced-custom-fields

I have been trying for few days, I think my brain doesn't get it well.

I am making a pdf parsing function from the ACF file upload field and I need the return value to be into a textarea field.

```
function extract_pdf_content( $value, $post_id, $field ) {
    // make sure the file exists and the Xpdf path was provided
    $xpdfPath = '/Users/michael/Sites/play/wp-content/pdftotext';

    // make sure it's a PDF
    $checkFileType = wp_check_filetype( $post_id );
    if ( 'pdf' !== strtolower( $checkFileType['ext'] ) ) {
        return $value;
    }

    // generate the full command to Xpdf's pdftotext binary
    $cmd = $xpdfPath . ' "' . $post_id . '" - -enc UTF-8';

    // @codingStandardsIgnoreStart
    // fire Xpdf
    @exec( $cmd, $output, $exitCode );
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd

    // grab the content
    $value = isset( $exitCode ) && 0 === $exitCode ? implode( ' ', $output ) : '';

    // clean up a little bit
    $value = trim( str_replace( "\n", ' ', $value ) );
    $value = sanitize_text_field( $value );


    function cv_update_value( $value ) {
    return $value;
    }
    add_filter('acf/update_value/name=cv', 'cv_update_value', 10, 3);

}
add_filter( 'acf/load_value/name=resume', 'extract_pdf_content', 10, 3 );
```

how to can this be possible?

[simple explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhQ9J.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your progress? what is your error? what is your problem?

Comment: it doesn't update the textarea value, no error in the debugging and no results either.

Comment: I do not see any textarea, nor any attempt to insert value into the DOM, please post your html and explain what you have tried.

Comment: It's a backend application, nothing for the front end, so there is not HTML or DOM.
The textarea field has name=cv , the file upload field name=resume